# iCSS floating divs

Tags: html, css

My picture explains what im trying to do, everything I have tried is breaking,

`position: fixed;` breaks when moving horizontal browser window size.

`position: absolute;` breaks when moving scrollbar down.

div1 is a image
div2-4 is css buttons.

[image]

Comment: Can you be more specific? I'm now shure what you want

Comment: im trying to float 3 buttons on the right side of the Div1, but not sure how to make it work

Comment: Does it matter to you if divs 2-4  are **inside** or **beside** div 1?

Comment: yes it matters, they are beside the div 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/opesor/1/edit)

Add the `blue` border like `border:5px solid blue;` ( you have to modify the `width and height` if you will use the  `border`).

Example with a `container`:

[JSBin_2](http://jsbin.com/opesor/3/edit)

I would advice you to use `fixed width` ( `not %` ).

Answer (score 2):

Use **float:left** for div 1, and **float:right** for div2 - 4. Also, set a width for the parent container (blue box in your picture).

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<div id="div1">
Div1
</div>

<div id="div2">
Div2
</div>

<div id="div3">
Div3
</div> 

<div id="div4">
Div4
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#div1,#div2,#div3,#div4{
background:#c00000;
}

#div1{
width:450px;
height:150px;
float:left;
padding:10px;
}

#div2,#div3,#div4{
width:160px;
margin-left:480px;
margin-bottom:10px;
padding:10px;
}
```